# Sqlite date parsing

Tags: java, sqlite, date

In a database I have a colunm with type DATE which contains data: *2017-05-09*

I get it like this:

```
Date sqlDate = rs.getDate("date"); //java:33
java.util.Date date = new Date(sqlDate.getTime());
```

error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing time stamp
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:327)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:346)
    at sqlite.Dao.selectByUser(Dao.java:33)x
    at sqlite.DaoTest.main(DaoTest.java:9)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-05-09" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
    at org.sqlite.date.FastDateParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:299)
    at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.parse(FastDateFormat.java:490)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:324)
    ... 3 more
```

Not sure how should I paste into database the date value?

From the sqlite docs

> A time string can be in any of the following formats: YYYY-MM-DD

What do they mean by the "time string" - that should be a string in the database?

Comment: Are you trying to insert data into the table or fetch the value from the table?

Comment: @user75ponic I inserted the data into the table manualy.

Comment: That means you are trying to read or retrieve data from the table?

Comment: @user75ponic not shure what do you mean because I get data from the table with jdbc by SELECT ...

Comment: You are quoting the SQLite documentation, but the error comes from Java's `getDate` function.

Comment: No, @CL., it’s the `getDate()` in the SQLite JDBC driver. It looks like the JDBC driver cannot parse the value from the database, weird.

Comment: As I read [the SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), SQLite does not have a DATE datatype. Am I in the wrong place, using the wrong doc link?

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm using SQLiteStudio manager ant it contais the type DATE.